# change button action to url address or bash script

Tags: php, forms, button

There is a button in a site like this:

```
<form method="POST" action = "/invite/1233">
   <input type="hidden" name="t" value="4b16d">
   <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

How can I "emulate" pressing this button for example in bash? Is it possible to make an adress that I can click instead of this button? Why `http://site-domain-here/invite/1233?t=4b16d` doesnt work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your terminal, assuming you have `curl` installed (who doesn't?), run:

```
curl -d "t=4b16d" http://site-domain-here/invite/1233
```

The `-d` option means that the request will be made with `POST`.

---

In response to your addition to your question:

> Why http://site-domain-here/invite/1233?t=4b16d doesnt work?

This is because by following the link above you are by default issuing a `GET` request; not a `POST` request with post data which is what the web page/service requires.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods for an explanation of the various HTTP request "verbs".